# SpringBootApplication does not recognize properties configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I have a simple properties configuration in package `psn.stats.config`

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/api.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

My `main` is in package `psn.stats` and looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
public class StatsServiceApplication {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run( StatsServiceApplication.class, args );
    }
}
```

Now I want to use properties values in on of the service class from package `psn.stats.connectors`. This class is here:

```
@Component
public class SomeAPIConnector {

    @Value( "${some.data.token.header}" )
    private String tokenHeader;
    @Value( "${some.data.token.value}" )
    private String token;
    @Value( "${some.data.api.address}" )
    private String apiAddress;
}
```

But when I run this app, all above fields are null. I don't know why SpringBoot does not read configuration with properties file. Can you help me with it?

Comment: Where does your api.properties live in relation to your root?  Make sure it's available on your classpath.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki - I said psn.stats for StatsServiceApplication  and psn.stats.config for AppConfig.

Comment: @levacjeep - \src\main\resources\api.properties - this is the place of this file

Comment: Can you also add your `api.properties` file? Is `some.data.token.header` defined there? Could it be that you are creating `SomeAPIConnector` with `new SomeAPIConnector()`?

Comment: 1) You shouldn't need to declare your own `PSPC` because Boot will do that for you, and 2) you need to show the class where you're using `SomeAPIConnector`, specifically including how you obtain the copy of it.

Comment: Ok, I solved it. It was my fault. I did not @Autowired Component but created it by `new`... Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In spring boot it is not necessary to add @PropertySource("classpath:/api.properties") only create an application.properties in src/main/resources spring boot will get all the properties and you can use them in  SomeAPIConnector,

In src/main/resources
   application.properties
the content could be:

some.data.token.header = XYZ

check out this: http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-application-configuration

Comment: But I want to have other name of this properties