# Configuring Connection Pool in Spring using database properties in java code

Tags: java, database, jdbc, datasource, connection-pooling

I need to configure Connection Pool in web application. Using common-dbcp i wrote:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    @Singleton
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?serverTimezone=UTC");
        basicDataSource.setUsername("name");
        basicDataSource.setPassword("password");
        basicDataSource.setInitialSize(5);
        basicDataSource.setMinIdle(3);
        basicDataSource.setMaxIdle(15);
        basicDataSource.setMaxWait(10000);
        basicDataSource.setMaxActive(100);
        return basicDataSource;
    }
}
```

I am trying to configure It with database.properties file.

```
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
    public class SpringConfig {
        private @Value("${propertyName}") String propertyField;

        @Bean
        @Singleton
        public DataSource getDataSource() {
            BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            basicDataSource.setConnectionProperties(propertyField);
            return basicDataSource;
        }
    }
```

I created database.properties and put It in directory *src/main/resources*.
The content is following:

```
driverClassName = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"
username="user"
password="password"
```

But It tells me "*property is unused"*. What i am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
*Solution is*:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/database.properties")
public class SpringConfig {
    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    @Singleton
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
            BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?serverTimezone=UTC");
            basicDataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("username"));
            basicDataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("password"));
            ..other actions is here
       }
}
```

*Important:*
You should `setUserName()` and `setPassword()` in the following order before other settings.

Comment: I am assuming this configuration is not for tests because tests require a different annotation. You mention that the file is in resources folder. Can you confirm if its src/main/resources? As detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52008941/537503) you don't need the @PropertySource annotation too. You also try using the jvm property "--spring.config.location=classpath:/another-location.properties" as detailed [here](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring) as an example.

Comment: @AndyDufresne ty, it was usefull also

Comment: It would be good if you accept this as an answer for others to refer it in future.

Comment: Of course, done. I can't vote because I don't have enough reputation, I am newcomer :)

Comment: 1: Solutions do not belong in questions, 2: This is not a 'solution' in my opinion since you need to map all properties upfront... Still remarkable dbcp has no real solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming this configuration is not for tests because tests require a different annotation. You mention that the file is in resources folder. Can you confirm if its src/main/resources? As detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52008941/537503) you don't need the @PropertySource annotation too. You also try using the jvm property "--spring.config.location=classpath:/another-location.properties" as detailed [here](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring) as an example.